# Python's graph-tool Segmentation fault on import

Tags: python, import, segmentation-fault, python-import, graph-tool

I'm experiencing a `Segmentation fault` while importing the `graph-tool` module into Python. I have conducted some tests:

1. `import graph_tool` doesn't result in any problems.

> ```
> >>> import graph_tool as gt
> >>> gt.__version__
> '2.29 (commit d4154c6c, Tue Aug 27 13:21:10 2019 +0000)'
> ```

2. `from graph_tool.all import *` results in `Segmentation fault`.

Upon executing `from graph_tool.draw import graph_draw` I get the same error (and the error stack) that I get with `from graph_tool.all import *`.

By using `faulthandler` I got the following output:

```
>>> from graph_tool.all import *
Fatal Python error: Segmentation fault

Current thread 0x00007fcc6e68d740 (most recent call first):
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219 in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 1043 in create_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 583 in module_from_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 670 in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967 in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983 in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219 in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1035 in _handle_fromlist
  File "<string>", line 1 in <module>
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/graph_tool/dl_import.py", line 61 in dl_import
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/graph_tool/draw/cairo_draw.py", line 89 in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219 in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728 in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677 in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967 in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983 in _find_and_load
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/graph_tool/draw/__init__.py", line 880 in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219 in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728 in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677 in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967 in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983 in _find_and_load
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/graph_tool/all.py", line 35 in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219 in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728 in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677 in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967 in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983 in _find_and_load
  File "<stdin>", line 1 in <module>
```

The OS:

```
   Static hostname: XXXXXXXXXXX
         Icon name: computer-vm
           Chassis: vm
        Machine ID: XXXXXXXXXXX
           Boot ID: XXXXXXXXXXX
    Virtualization: vmware
  Operating System: CentOS Linux 7 (Core)
       CPE OS Name: cpe:/o:centos:centos:7
            Kernel: Linux 3.10.0-1062.4.3.el7.x86_64
      Architecture: x86-64
```

Python is from Anaconda:

```
(base) -bash-4.2$ python --version
Python 3.7.3
(base) -bash-4.2$ conda --version
conda 4.8.0
```

One lead that I've been following is the fact that the problematic import (please see no. 2) works on other server that have the following configuration:

- `Python 3.7.6`
- `Conda 4.8.0`
- `graph_tool` version is the same as in the case I'm trying to solve.

One difference that stands out is the number of pending signals in `ulimit -a` (other values returned by the command are identical). The server that the import works on has 256898 pending signals and the server affected by the problem has 127882. I tried increasing the lower value but I couldn't since `pending signals: cannot modify limit: Operation not permitted.`

Please note that I have posted the same problem as an issue in the `graph-tool`'s GitLab [repo](https://git.skewed.de/count0/graph-tool/issues/621). I decided to ask a question on StackOverflow because the audience may be bigger here than in the repo's issue queue.